# pandas notebooks into a python process

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, scipy

I have a total of 7 jupyter notebooks.

The global.ipynb   has variables that are used in multiple notebooks.

The inputdata.ipynb has input files that are converted into data frames.

PRG2.ipynb uses data (basically data frames created ) from (global, input data, prg1)

Prg4.ipynb uses data (basically data frames created )  from (global, inputdata, prg2)

Prg5.ipynb uses data (basically data frames created ) from (global, inputdata, prg2)

Prg6.ipynb uses data (basically data frames created )  from (global, inputdata, prg2)

Prg7.ipynb uses data (basically data frames created ) from (global, inputdata, prg4, prg5, prg6,prg3).

How do I convert the above thing into a nice python process ( say final.py). (something like each notebook as function or each notebook as .py program and importing or can we use oops here). If you can provide a **Pseudo code** of layout what you think is best is really helpful.   Please provide your thoughts on how would you do that. **Pesudo code** is very much helpful and much appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: What you need is %%load and nbconvert.